# unexpected token parsing XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I've been looking at this for over an hour trying to figure out the problem without any luck. I am not quite sure what is wrong, I am working on my custom hotkey system. Any help would be appreciated.

> '<' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 3, position 19

```
<Root>
<keyCodes>https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx</keyCodes>
<hotkeyToggle>&HA3</hotkeyToggle>
<reattachGame>&H74</reattachGame>
<toggleMenu>&H2D</toggleMenu>
[...]
```

Comment: The character _&_ should be changed to  _&amp;_

Comment: http://www.xmlvalidation.com   The stuff inside your tags is an entity. You need to escape the &

Answer (score 0):

You either mean `&amp;HA3` (the content being a literal string "&HA3", where you have to XML-escape `&` as `&amp;` otherwise XML will consider it a broken XML-entity) or the XML-entity `&#xA3;` (a byte with hex value 0xA3).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help that fixed my problem!